# How to refer to "earlier" letters in the alphabet?

Tags: word-choice, alphabet, sort-ordering

Concerning the order of letters in the alphabet, how does one refer to "earlier" letters?

For example, "Names starting with "earlier" letters come first in lists."

Would that be "earlier," "higher," "greater," or what?

Adding a tad bit more context, I am actually looking for the most proper way to write the sentence I used as an example. If I'm being confusing, I'll try to better explain myself after some sleep.

Comment: A `precedes` B alphabetically. B `follows` A.

Comment: That's helpful in regards to the relationship between letters, but I'm looking for the relationship of letters to the alphabet itself. If 1 is `smaller` than 2, A is `smaller?` than B? Smaller is certainly not the correct word, but I'm not sure what is.

Comment: A `comes earlier` than B. A `is earlier` than B.

Comment: You are referring to the order of the letters in the alphabet, not their size. Hence to say a letter is smaller; or greater; or higher would be incorrect. You could say, earlier if the letters had already been nominated.

Comment: Would `prior` work?

Comment: @Meepinator: A is lexicographically smaller than B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are referring to [lexicographic(al) ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). In more general terms, A is *lexicographically smaller* than B if A *precedes* B in some alphabet X.

I don't think many people without math/computer science backgrounds would understand these terms though.

Comment: Though it's a tad bit too technically worded for what I needed, this sounds quite close to what I was looking for.

Comment: Okay, let me start this comment off with this disclaimer: I am not knowledgeable in this, or in other words, I really don't know what I'm talking about here! But here's my question: My understanding, such as it is, is that a lexicographical order is really a sort of backwards construction of a numerical sequence as compared to an alphabetical string. In other words, it's a way of defining a mathematical sequence in comparison to an alphabet, and therefore it is not a way of describing an alphabet. It therefore does not APPLY to an alphabet. It applies to NUMBERS. Correct me, please.

Comment: Notice that even in the Wikipedia reference you cite, the lexicographical order when applied to an alphabet still does not allow for calling A _smaller_ than B. It says A comes before B, doesn't it? Yes, it does. I think some value in some computing sequence might be lexicographically smaller than some other value, but I just don't think it is valid to say that A is lexicographically smaller than B. A comes ahead of, is prior to, precedes, or comes before, B, but I just don't accept any way it's smaller.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg: It is a generalization of the alphabetical ordering of words.

The term "lexicographically smaller" is certainly used in math/programming contexts (see e.g. http://books.google.be/books?id=9sbsMkuFzhYC&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=lexicographically+smaller&source=bl&ots=sWONq25VOf&sig=WXbcgfCJBcsikOs_JmmSD1Thvz0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EVQiUr7bKMjVsgb-r4DIDA&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=lexicographically%20smaller&f=false, http://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/lexicographically-next-permutation/, http://www.codechef.com/problems/SUBANAGR).

Comment: The term, lexicographically smaller, is appropriate in a computer or mathematical context, you have me convinced there. But there is no way that someone would use this term in a normal every-day-like situation, which the OP specified in his question. Say: *"Names starting with a lexicographically smaller letter than F"* and you'd only have people replying, *"eh?"* Despite your back-up evidence, I think @JohnM.Landsberg is still correct to assert that the term is a mathematical one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Did I say otherwise? Furthermore, I never saw any specification of "a normal every-day-like situation" in the question of the OP.

Comment: Well the OP's example sentence suggests otherwise; and if he were looking for a mathematical/computer science term I'm sure he would have asked in a different exchange site. In any case, the OP accepted your answer, and I was only expressing my perplexity.

Comment: I would prefer _lexicographically prior to_ or _less than,_ but this is on the right track.

Comment: @BraddSzonye: You're right, I also prefer "lexicographically less than" but was also led by OP's original question of A .. smaller than B. "Less than" definitely makes more sense as it is immediately less confusing/abusing the < notation.

Answer (score 4):

"Precedes" is literally correct, although colloquially we usually say that A "comes ahead of" B in the alphabet. And, flipped around, we say B "comes after" A.

And by the way, although it is not exactly incorrect to say that 1 is "smaller than" 2, we generally say it is "less than" 2, not "smaller than."

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly (and to quote the words you use):

You are "actually looking for the most proper way to write the sentence [you] used as an example", namely:

> Names starting with "earlier" letters come first in lists.

Personally, I would rewrite that as:

> Names are listed alphabetically.
>   Names are listed in alphabetic order.

If you want to retain a similar format to your example:

> Names starting with letters earlier in the alphabet ...
>   Names starting with alphabetically earlier letters ...
>   Names higher up the alphabet ...

but personally, I'm not keen of any of those alternatives.

More importantly, in referring to "Names *starting with* ... letters ...", you could be understood as implying that only the *first* letter is taken into consideration in determining the order, such that you could have a sequence such as:

> Howe, Holmes, Hancock, Hill, Hughes

whereas true alphabetical order would take into account *all* letters in the name (as far a necessary) to give:

> Hancock, Hill, Holmes, Howe, Hughes

Comment: As always, yours is the most logical answer.

Comment: @TrevorD - You said it better. Upvoted your answer and deleted mine (since this site is supposed to be about answers). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

> If your surnames start with any letter **between** H and P ....
>
> Those whose surnames begin with any letter **before** H ...
>    Those whose surnames begin with any letter **after** P...

**Edit:**
Because some users have revised their answers that make mine look superfluous.

Using the OP's original example, I would like to offer the following solution:

> Names starting with the ***first three/six letters of the alphabet*** come
>   first in lists.

Not pithy I grant you, but certainly easily understood by all.

Comment: I like _between_ and would upvote but your two last examples are not correct. The surnames cannot begin before or after anything, they can only begin with _letters_ that come _before_ or _after_. In any case, _begin with before_ is grammatically wrong.

Comment: @terdon  I was in a rush to go to work. My bad, I hadn't noticed my mistake. I'll correct it. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, downvote retracted and upvote added.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the "head" of the alphabet.

> **head** 5a : the end that is upper or higher or opposite the foot   b : the source of a stream

*from m-w.com*

Comment: after closer inspection this is pretty close to John's answer of "ahead of"